# How to pass data to mail view using queue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have my job class `ProductPublish` method `handle()` I am trying to send email.

```
public function handle()
{
   //
    Mail::to('i******o@gmail.com')->send(new SendEmail());
}
```

In the `ProductController` controller I am calling that job class as like below

```
ProductPublish::dispatch();
```

In the SendEmail class which is mailable I am trying to pass data to view as like below

```
public $message;
public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = 'This is test message';
}
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email.product.product-publish')->with('message' => $this->message); 
}
```

But it does not works. I also tried with no attaching `with()` method but still does getting result. In the email view I am calling data as like below

```
{{ $message }}
```

Can someone kindly guide me what can be issue that it is not working. Also I want to pass data actually from `ProductController` but since I am failed to pass from `sendEmail` that's I didn't tried yet from controller.

Kindly guide me how can I fix it.

Comment: What errors do you get, or are you queues running?

Answer (score 2):

In laravel,

`The arguments passed to the dispatch method will be given to the job's constructor`

So when you are calling dispatch, you can pass message :

```
ProductPublish::dispatch($message);
```

Then inside your job you can add a property `message` and a constructor to get it from dispatch and assign it :

```
private $message;

public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function handle()
{
   // Use the message using $this->messge
    Mail::to('i******o@gmail.com')->send(new SendEmail($this->message));
}
```

Also you can directly queue emails. Check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#queueing-mail)

Comment: it is not working I have tried it, should I use message variable into SendEmail also or not ?

Comment: yes, when we are doing `new SendEmail($this->message)` the message is then passed to the constructor of your `SendEmail` class

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public $message;

public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message= $message;
}

public function build()
{
    // Array for passing template
    $input = array(
                      'message'     => $this->message
                  );

    return $this->view('email.product.product-publish')
                ->with([
                    'inputs' => $input,
                  ]);
}
```

Check [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#configuring-the-view)